# How to ping redis cache using ping class in .net?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, redis

I want to check status of my redis cache my using `ping.SendPingAsync` request. But I am not sure what IP address should I provide. For my local the server is 127.0.0.1 and by sending ping request, it's returning success but for dev and test the server is "11.**.***.***:6379,password=******" so how can I ping this host?

Comment: What's the problem with using that IP address? You have to use that IP just to connect to Redis, why can't you use it with `SendPingAsync`?

Comment: I just want to make sure do I need to provide password and port as well or just ip address like "11.**.***.****"

Comment: PING works at the TCP level. It knows nothing about applications and their passwords